# MVC4 Entity Framework Controller Database Issue

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to perform an insert or update from my controller but I get an error message stating that 'ICN.CourierClient does not contain a definition' of my various properties like 'Address' - when in fact it does, and my other similar calls to other database models work fine with the same code.  Did I miss a reference or some configuration somewhere, I have it defined in the same way as my other models in my dbset statements:

```
    public DbSet<Courier> Couriers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CourierClient> CourierClients { get; set; }

    IQueryable<Courier> Datasource.Couriers { get { return Couriers; } }
    IQueryable<Driver> Datasource.Drivers  { get { return Drivers; } }
    IQueryable<Job> Datasource.Jobs { get { return Jobs; } }
    IQueryable<CourierClient> Datasource.CourierClients { get { return CourierClients; } }
```

---

```
            IEnumerable<CourierClient> client = null;
            client = from c in db.CourierClients where c.ClientName == job.PickupCompanyName select c;

            if (client != null)
            {
                client.Address = job.PickupAddress1;
                client.City = job.PickupCity;
                client.State = job.PickupState;
                client.Zip = job.PickupZip;
                client.Phone = job.PickupPhone;
                db.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            else
            {
                client.ClientName = job.PickupCompanyName;
                client.Address = job.PickupAddress1;
                client.City = job.PickupCity;
                client.State = job.PickupState;
                client.Zip = job.PickupZip;
                client.Phone = job.PickupPhone;
                db.CourierClients.Add(client);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
```

---

```
    public class CourierClient
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual string ClientName { get; set; }

    public virtual string ContactName { get; set; }

    public virtual string Address { get; set; }

    public virtual string City { get; set; }

    public virtual string State { get; set; }

    public virtual string Zip { get; set; }

    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }

    public virtual string Fax { get; set; }

    public virtual string Email { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What does the CourierClients entity look like? And can you provide the exact error?

Comment: entity posted above, error messages posted to answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `client` as `IEnumerable<CourierClient>`. That is why compiler tells you that it does not have properties, which you expect to find in `CourierClient`.

```
        CourierClient client = (from c in db.CourierClients where c.ClientName == job.PickupCompanyName select c).SingleOrDefault();
        if (client != null)
        {
            client.Address = job.PickupAddress1;
            client.City = job.PickupCity;
            client.State = job.PickupState;
            client.Zip = job.PickupZip;
            client.Phone = job.PickupPhone;
            db.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            client = new CourierClient();
            client.ClientName = job.PickupCompanyName;
            client.Address = job.PickupAddress1;
            client.City = job.PickupCity;
            client.State = job.PickupState;
            client.Zip = job.PickupZip;
            client.Phone = job.PickupPhone;
            db.CourierClients.Add(client);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
```

Note the creation of the instance of `CourierClient` if it was not found.

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'ICN.CourierClient' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ICN.CourierClient>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\ICN\ICN August\ICN August\Controllers\JobController.cs 241 53 ICN August

Comment: Error 2 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ICN.CourierClient>' does not contain a definition for 'Address' and no extension method 'Address' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ICN.CourierClient>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\ICN\ICN August\ICN August\Controllers\JobController.cs 245 28 ICN August

Comment: I tried the declaration as you suggested and I can a series of error message posted above.    IEnumerable<CourierClient> client = (from c in db.CourierClients where c.ClientName == job.PickupCompanyName select c).SingleOrDefault();

Comment: THIS WORKS, THANKS! CourierClient ExistingClient = new CourierClient();
ExistingClient = (from c in db.CourierClients where c.ClientName == job.PickupCompanyName select c).SingleOrDefault();